# ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably a simple task, but for some reason I’m not quite getting it right.

I want to save a copy of the active workbook to a different file. I have used a code in the past to do this with the date, but I want to remove the date. The code I used in the past is the following:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "P:\Wealth Management Products & Services\Investment Research & Communication\Structured Products\" &Format(dtdate) & " " & "Structured Product Tool" & " " & "Bloomberg" &".xlsm"
```

What I want is to remove the date, so the name will be: **Structured Product Tool Bloomberg**

I thought it would be the following:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "P:\Wealth Management Products Services\Investment Research & Communication\Structured Products\"Structured Product Tool" & " " & "Bloomberg" & ".xlsm"
```

But I’m getting an error.

Does anyone know the correct code for this?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: Try `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "P:\Wealth Management Products & Services\Investment Research & Communication\Structured Products\Structured Product Tool Bloomberg.xlsm"`

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Thanks JvdV, that did the trick. Peter

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an ampersand `&` in your statement:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "P:\Wealth Management Products & Services\Investment" _
    & "Research & Communication\Structured Products\" _
    & "Structured Product Tool" & " " & "Bloomberg" & ".xlsm"
```